# How to remove file from feature branch?

Tags: git

I have a featurebranch that branches of a remote develop branch. Now I have pulled the feature locally. I want to undo updates on 1 file so basically revert all changed changes on that file so it matches the remote develop again. I tried `git checkout origin/master filename` but then I get:

> error: pathspec 'origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git

How can I revert the changes on 1 file in the feature so it is not present in the feature anymore?

Comment: just `git checkout origin/master -- file`

Answer (score 0):

Try: `git checkout origin/master -- filename`.  Sometimes the `--` is necessary to delineate the pathspecs from the rest of the command line when git can't figure it out automagically.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake the remote was called something else not origin. So git `checkout otherremote/master filename` without the -- worked for me.